# Spark- Exception in thread java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pmml

I am trying to score a model from pmml file using pmml4s library. Every time I submit the job in Spark I get the following error:

```
20/05/13 23:30:10 ERROR SparkSubmit: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.names(). 
[Ljava/lang/String;
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.names(). 
    [Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.pmml4s.spark.ScoreModel.transform(ScoreModel.scala:56)
    at com.aexp.JavaPMML.main(JavaPMML.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
```

Following is my code sample:

```
ScoreModel model = ScoreModel.fromFile(args[0]);
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
Dataset<?> df = spark.read().format("csv")
                     .option("header", "true")
                     .option("inferSchema", "true")
                     .load(args[1]);

Dataset<?> scoreDf = model.transform(df);
```

Following is the pom file that I am using:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pmml4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmml4s-spark_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have edited my pom file and made the spark version similar still I face the same issue. When I am using Scala, I am facing the same problem. Is there any dependency that I am missing?

Comment: Why are you using different versions of spark libraries?

Comment: I have made the spark versions similar, still I face the same issue.

Comment: is this issue fixed ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use same `version` of spark libraries. If spark versions are not matching we will be getting `NoSuchMethodError` issue in many places as those methods might have modified or removed in latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the PMML4S-Spark used the method `names` of StructType, which is introduced since Spark 2.4. Now it has been fixed in the latest PMML4S-Spark `0.9.5`. Please, update your pom file to use the new version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pmml4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmml4s-spark_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
```